# django error using autocomplete_light

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, django-forms

I'm trying to use autocomplete-light in a form field.
When I'm trying to use the field I get 
`FieldError at /autocomplete/icd_10Autocomplete/
Cannot resolve keyword u'name' into field. Choices are: icd_10_code, icd_10_desc, id`

`icd_10_code, icd_10_desc, id` are the fields from icd_10 table but I want to retrieve data only form `icd_10_codes` field.

icd_10_code in Diagnosis model is a foreing key in icd_10.icd_10.code field. When I'm trying to write a value in Diagnosis.icd_10_code I want the form to autocomplete the word, looking words stored in icd_10.icd_10_code fields.

Any idea?

**forms.py**

```
import autocomplete_light

autocomplete_light.register(icd_10)
autocomplete_light.autodiscover()

class DiagnosisForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DiagnosisForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper=FormHelper(self)
        self.fields['icd_10_code']= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=icd_10, widget=autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget("icd_10Autocomplete"))

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            # 'patient',
            'age_of_diagnosis',
            'icd_10_code',

            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', "Save changes"),
                Submit('cancel',"Cancel")
            ),
        )
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_show_labels = True

    class Meta:
        model = Diagnosis
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `ModelForm` you should use

```
class Meta:
    exclude = (
        'name',
        'somefield',
        'someotherfield',
        )
```

if you don't want that model field to be passed to the form. You can include any other field that shouldn't go to the form in this tuple. Otherwise the form is expecting that user should provide a value for theese fields anyways.

It is also not very clear at what point in time do you recieve your error and what is the underlying `Diagnosis` model.

Comment: I want icd_10_code to be passed to the form! I want this field to get a value using autocomplete. I receive this error when I'm trying to write some text in the autocomplete form.

Comment: icd_10_code in Diagnosis model is a foreing key in icd_10.icd_10.code field. When I'm trying to write a value in Diagnosis.icd_10_code I want the form to autocomplete the word, looking words stored in icd_10.icd_10_code fields.

Comment: It seems that in your call to autocomplete_light.register(icd_10) you should also provide - search_fields=['icd_10_code'] otherwise if you don't provide this kwarg it defaults to 'name' and tries to search on this field in the model icd_10

Comment: Thanks! That's it!! I included `search_fields=['icd_10_code']` in registration and my problem solved! :-)